# Order of operations parenthesis

Tags: calculus

When you have an equation set out like 
(2)(2)^3

Would you multiply both the parenthesis (2x2 = 4) then take 4^3, or would you do (2)^3 multiplied by 2?

I know this is such a basic question but I cant for the life of me remember.
Thanks!

Comment: It's the latter. Remember, exponents only apply to the closest factor. To extend their scope, you would need to furnish a grouping symbol around a larger set of factors. You may be doing this mentally in the first case (incorrectly).

Answer (score 0):

BEDMAS:
Brackets
Exponents
Division
Multiplication
Addition
Subtraction

$$(2)(2)^3=(2)(8)=16$$